# getDate with day of the week in PDF

Tags: date

In our PDF we display the date of the order with this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getPdfHelper()->getDate()?>

public function _getDate($format = 'd-F-Y-H:i')
{
    return date($format, Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp());
}
```

Currently it is displayed as 2 Jan. 2015.

But we want to change this into Friday 2 January 2015.

What code do we need for this?

Comment: What is this  `getPdfHelper` method? I did not find any trace of it. What file is that?

Comment: That is from the Fooman Pdf Customiser extension, that we use for PDF customization

Comment: Then either ask Fooman, or post the `getDate` method in here if the license allows you.

Comment: I edit my question, with the getDate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<?php echo $this->getPdfHelper()->getDate()?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $this->getPdfHelper()->getDate('l d F Y')?>
```

[See this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for additional date formats